# flatMap to streamToRx never completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I have this test

```
const Rx = require('rx')
const fs = require('fs')
const {streamToRx} = require('rxjs-stream')

it('should not be infinite', done => {
  let streamObservable = streamToRx(fs.createReadStream('/some/file.txt'));
  Rx.Observable.of(1).flatMap(any => streamObservable)
  // streamObservable
    .map(any => 'file processed')
    .subscribe(x => console.log('next', x), err => {
        console.error(err)
        done(err)
      },
      () => {
        console.log('complete!')
        done()
      }
    )
})
```

This test timesout - means the stream never completes. However when I don't chain with flatMap like this:

```
const Rx = require('rx')
const fs = require('fs')
const {streamToRx} = require('rxjs-stream')

it('should not be infinite', done => {
  let streamObservable = streamToRx(fs.createReadStream('/some/file.txt'));
  // Rx.Observable.of(1).flatMap(any => streamObservable)
  streamObservable
    .map(any => 'file processed')
    .subscribe(x => console.log('next', x), err => {
        console.error(err)
        done(err)
      },
      () => {
        console.log('complete!')
        done()
      }
    )
})
```

then the output is:

```
next file processed
complete!
```

What am I doing wrong when chaining up these observables? This seems to happen only when the second one is converted from stream with rxjs-stream.

Comment: this seems to be a bug in rxjs-stream? Tried with RxNode.fromStream and it worked

Comment: Technically, there should be no difference.

Comment: I had a look at the `RxNode.fromStream` and `rxjs-stream.streamToRx` code and `RxNode.fromStream` creates and returns a *cold* Observable whereas `streamToRx` incorrectly returns a *hot* Observable (in this case a Subject). In your example, `createReadStream` therefore executes and resolves at the point of invocation and subsequent subscriptions therefore subscribe to a `fs.readStream` that already resolved. In short, it's a bug in `streamToRx`.

Comment: hey @Jeremy thanks, make it an answer, I'd accept it

Comment: hey @macias. I made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the `RxNode.fromStream` and `rxjs-stream.streamToRx` code and `RxNode.fromStream` creates and returns a cold Observable whereas `streamToRx` incorrectly returns a hot Observable (in this case a Subject).

In your example, `createReadStream` therefore executes and resolves at the point of invocation and subsequent subscriptions therefore subscribe to a `fs.readStream` that already resolved. In short, it's a bug in `streamToRx`.